# Secure login and authorization with cookies only in PHP

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I'm building a login system for multiple projects with only cookies and a database. I've read a few answers on SO and other websites, but I'm still not sure if my own answers are correct or if I'm missing something.

## What I have so far

I first used a cookie *user_id* that I used to identify the user. I made a change making the session tokens unique and identifying a user from there. It saves a cookie, a database request and doesn't reveal the user's id.

#### Database tables

1. *users*(*user_id*, *level*)

   - *level* is an tinyint field with the user authorization levels.
2. *sessions*(*token*, *user_id*)

   - *token* is an indexed char field with **hashed** tokens

#### Cookies

1. *session_token*: holds ***un*hashed** *token*

Note: The database table *sessions* holds the hashed version of the *session_token*, so that if a hacker has access to the table data, he does not have direct access to the raw tokens.

#### Code

```
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
$token_hash = hash($algo, $token);
```

## Questions

1. Is this the right way to make a token and also the right way to hash the token?
2. What `$length` should be used? Does more characters mean better security?
3. What `$algo` should be used?
4. Is security reduced if you hash a larger string than the hash will output?

#### My answers

These are my own answers. But, like I said, I don't know if they're correct. I've written them down just to give a better idea of how I think about the subject.

1. It is, because `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` is safe for making tokens. The hash is easily made and can be executed every time the user loads a page to check the user's *level*
2. 128 characters should be good. `bin2hex()` will output 256 characters. Of course more characters mean better security, because a brute force attack will have a smaller chance of being successful.
3. Use sha512, it outputs 128 characters. A good compromise between better security and speed.
4. Would think so, because there's more chance of duplicates. But that means answer 2 should say 64 characters.

## Additional information

- Loggin in would create a new entry in the sessions table with an unique token. Multiple sessions per user are allowed for multiple devices/browsers.
- Validating a user (happens on every page a logged in user requests) would be checking if the user is logged in by comparing the *session_token* cookie with the data stored in the *sessions* table. In the same request the *level* will be fetched from the *users* table and compared to the level needed for the requested page.

Comment: Why do you throw away half of the entropy you've collected with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`?

Comment: I was using `bin2hex()` because I didn't know the raw output of `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` would be cookie/database friendly, is it?

Comment: Handling raw data takes more effort to make sure it's escaped properly.

Comment: By using PDO's bindParam it should be ok on the database side. Does it automatically work on the cookie side? What's better to use, entropy-wise, the raw `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()` output or the `bin2hex()` output?

Comment: Cookie values are URL-encoded. Representing 256 raw bytes requires, on average, 24% more characters (which don't contribute to entropy) than simply using `bin2hex()`.

Comment: Why do you keep the user_id in the cookie? You can index the sessions table on the token and then get the user id from there.

Comment: Right, that was also my idea, but then I would have to check for duplicate session tokens every time a user logs in e.g. with a `while` loop. Do you think that is a better approach, if so, why? I can think of one less database request and one less cookie.

Comment: You only have to worry about duplicate tokens when you create a new token; with 128 bytes of entropy, the chance of hitting a duplicate (and needing more than one query) is very low. The idea is that you share as little information about a user as possible; if you can hide a user id, do it.

Comment: I'm going with the one cookie method. The chance of duplicate tokens is indeed very low and it saves a cookie, a database request and hides the user id. It's also easier to maintain.